# Meaning of this shell script line with awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I read this line of script in book [linux device drivers]. What does it do?

```
major=$(awk "\\$2=  =\"$module\" {print \\$1}" /proc/devices)
```

as in context:

```
#!/bin/sh
module="scull"   
device="scull"  
mode="664"

# invoke insmod with all arguments we got  
# and use a pathname, as newer modutils don't look in . by default

/sbin/insmod ./$module.ko $* || exit 1


# remove stale nodes  
rm -f /dev/${device}[0-3]   

major=$(awk "\\$2=  =\"$module\" {print \\$1}" /proc/devices)

mknod /dev/${device}0 c $major 0
....
```

Comment: Whatever book you read that in, burn it. At least half of the lines in that script have at least one bug on each of them and the way it's invoking awk is just ridiculous.

Comment: @EdMorton kindly suggest a replacement book...

Comment: For shell: Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson. For awk: Effective Awk Programming by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read this too but that line was not working for me. I had to modify it to

```
major=$(awk "\$2 == \"$module\" {print \$1}" /proc/devices)
```

The first part `\$2 == \"$module\"` is the pattern. When this is satisfied, that is, the second column is equal to "scull", the command `print \$1` is executed which prints the first column. This value is stored in the variable major.
The `$` needs to be escaped as they need to be passed as it is to awk.

Comment: No!!! I can't believe this was accepted as the correct answer! See the correct answer by @Guru

Comment: @EdMorton it's not an incorrect explanation of the code as given, so it's fine.

Comment: @cmh - that reminds me of the joke about the guy getting lost in the fog in Seattle so he pulled up to a building and asked where he was and the answer he got was "in a car". Given that information he could then find his way home as he knew that since he just got a perfectly correct and perfectly useless answer he must be at the Microsoft building. Interpreting buggy code without correcting it isn't useful IMHO.

Answer (score 8):

A better way to write this would be :

```
major=$(awk -v mod=$module '$2==mod{print $1}' /proc/devices)
```

Comment: +1 I was just writing something similar. This is the correct way to pass shell vars to awk.

Comment: +1 Almost correct, just quote your shell variable: `mod="$module"`.

Answer (score 1):

`/proc/devices` contains the currently configured character and block devices for each module.

Expanding a few variables in your context, and fixing the syntax error in the equality, the command looks like this:

```
awk '$2=="scull" {print $1}' /proc/devices
```

This means "if the value of the second column is `scull`, then output the first column."

This command is run in a subshell — `$(...)` — and the output is assigned to the variable `$major`.

The explanation of the purpose is [in the book](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-3-sect-2#chp-3-ITERM-4388):

> The script to load a module that has been assigned a dynamic number can, therefore, be written using a tool such as `awk` to retrieve information from `/proc/devices` in order to create the files in `/dev`.

Note that in [the distributed examples](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596005900/), the line in `scull_load` matches Vivek's correction.